# Java Inheritance : 2nd instance calls 1st instance method

Tags: java, android, inheritance

I have a very strange problem with a java class in my android application.

I have some sub classes which extend my abstract class GameDialog

**GameDialog class**

```
public abstract class GameDialog extends Sprite
{
    private static boolean gd_visible = false;

    protected GameDialog(GameScene scene, Camera camera, VertexBufferObjectManager pSpriteVertexBufferObject){
        ...
    }

    public boolean display(){
        if(!GameDialog.gd_visible) {
            ...
        }
    }

    protected boolean hide(){
        if(GameDialog.gd_visible){
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**PauseDialog class**

```
public class PauseDialog extends GameDialog {

    public PauseDialog(GameScene scene, Camera camera, VertexBufferObjectManager pSpriteVertexBufferObject) {
        super(scene, camera, pSpriteVertexBufferObject);
        ...
        final ButtonSprite play_button = new ButtonSprite(...);
        play_button.setOnClickListener(setPlayButtonListener());
    }


    private OnClickListener setPlayButtonListener() {
        return new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ButtonSprite pButtonSprite, float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
                hide();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Each time I want to display a dialog, I write this line :
new PauseDialog(GameScene.this, camera, vbom).display();

The first time, it works well : the dialog is displayed, user make a choice and it's hidden.
But the 2nd time, the dialog is not hidden (after user's choice).

I used the debugger to see what's going on, and the conclusion is :

- **In the 2nd instance, it calls the hide() method of the first instance !**

If some one can explain me what it is doing that ... Thank you.

Comment: I think we probably do not have enough information. The way you post it, it is just as impossible as you say. hide() gets called by the instance-specific click listener, on its own instance object. So for starters: how do you conclude that it's the same instance? And how does the PauseDialog get created and shown?

Comment: I understand my problem actually. Writing this post and summaring my code help me to understand. The problem is the engine I use. At the first hide(), textures dialog (window & button) are deleted but the touchArea for the button is still there. That's why I had this problem : at the second time, you have the feeling to click on the second dialog's button but instead it still the first one ...

Answer (score 0):

It is because     `gd_visible` is `static`. Delete the static keyword and it should work. Static fields doesn't belong to the instances but they belong to the class.

Comment: No I need this static field. I use it to be sure that only one dialog is displayed at a time.